# Выборка из двух таблиц с двумя условиями и подсчетами

Tags: sql, mysql

Сразу скажу, что я читал и документацию, и статьи, но это не сильно мне помогло, поэтому под конец дня решил обратиться за помощью сюда.

Суть проблемы:
Имеются две таблицы: registrations и users. У каждой регистрации есть два аргумента и  реферальный идентификатор. У пользователей из примечательного есть поле selected.   
Итого:

```
registrations  
=============
id - int  
arg1  - double  
arg2 - double  
refid  - int

users
=====
id - int  
selected - int
```

1. Мне нужно выбрать пользователей, у которых `selected = 1` из `users`.
2. Для каждого из этих пользователей нужно посчитать сумму сумм двух аргументов в таблице `registrations`, где `refid` равен `id` пользователя из users (то есть для пользователя с `id=5` получить все записи из registrations c `refid=5` и получить сумму значений `arg1+arg2` для каждой записи из `registrations`).
3. В результате нужно получить все поля пользователей (как при `SELECT * FROM users WHERE selected=1`) и дополнительное с результатом 2-го пункта.

Читал про join'ы и функции по типу sum, но сложить это все в один запрос вообще не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается и во что углубляться.

**Обновление**

Мне нужны все юзеры с `selected=1`, даже если у них нет рефералов.

Если у пользователя 3 реферала, то этого пользователя нужно вернуть 1 раз, а в поле `sum_args` нужно вывести сумму результатов `arg1+arg2` для каждого реферала. То есть:

```
id     arg1    arg2    refid
1       12      75       7
2       46      89       7
3       16       3       7
```

В sum_args для пользователя с id=7 должно получиться (12+75) + (46+89) + (16+3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, SUM(r.arg1+r.arg2) FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN registrations r ON u.id = r.refid
WHERE u.selected=1
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: С учетом уточнений здесь надо inner join заменить на left join и суммы для возможных null обнулить.  

    select ... sum(ifnull(arg1,0)+ifnull(arg2,0)) ...
      left join registrations ...

Comment: спасибо, все так.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, как-то так:

```
SELECT reg.*, reg.arg1 + reg.arg2 as sum_args 
FROM registrations reg, users u 
WHERE u.selected=1 AND u.id=reg.refid
```

**=== Обновление**

Смутили вы меня оператором SUM. :-)

Сейчас запрос работает правильно.
Пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78fa8/5

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: по совету @Yura Ivanov уточнил вопрос, буду благодарен за правку, т.к. у самого не получается

Comment: @Get, пользуйтесь, пожалуйста, ansi join'ами. 

[SO:ANSI vs. non-ANSI SQL JOIN syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax)

> It's good practice as most developers and dba's will use ANSI-92 nowadays and you should follow the standard. Certainly all modern query tools will generate ANSI-92.